# Is it possible to send and receive emails from a parked domain?

Tags: email, dns

One of my friends got a job offer from an email like
name@somedomain.com. When opening the domain one can easily recognise that its parked.
I checked with Who.Is and found its registered by register.com.

Verifying the email at http://www.infobyip.com/verifyemailaccount.php
says the email exists.
So is it possible to send and receive emails from a parked domain?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally a parked website does mean no services, however, it is possible that lets say the company hasnt paid, so the domain has gone into parked, but all their services are still setup to email.. Because their server still accepts the domain, theres every chance the mail would get through.

However - its not a good sign for an employee that your future employer didnt pay up for their hosting..

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's absolutely possible to send email from parked domains.  Parking means it's registered but the user hasn't done anything/much with it.  Depending on if it's a register-level park or a host-level park a domain could have some or all services and still appear "parked" when visiting through the web.

In many cases when you register a domain with a company that provides hosting & registration - the domain will appear with a parking style web page - even though it's up and running and paid for.  Until the user uploads their website that page will stay (sometimes it can be years!  Because the supply of good domains is getting limited people will claim the domain as soon as they have an idea taking weeks, months, years to release the service).

All that said... it's tough to take a potential employer seriously if they don't even have an information page loaded instead of the host default parked page.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia, "Domain parking is the registration of an Internet domain name without using it for services such as e-mail or a website i.e. without placing any content on the domain" -- so, if a domain is truly parked, it cannot be used for email.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Wikipedia. But for your reference here is what CPanel says: http://etwiki.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/CpanelDocs/ParkedDomains

Comment: Yeah, but you assume that because a domain is parked, it CANNOT have email. It's false : the registrar can provide a mail address, and it will still be considered as parked if there isn't any valuable content on it and if it's for sale.

Comment: Yeah right, most of the time it's okay. But especially when it comes to technical topics where everyone thinks, they are specialists, my trust is limited.